# When does magento pull transactional emails from template files vs. CMS?

Tags: magento-1.7, email-templates

We have configured our emails in the Magento CMS under

```
system > transactional emails
```

However, I've noticed now that after placing an order, the email is using the template file located in

```
/app/locale/en_US/template/email/sales/order_new_guest.html
```

Why is Magento pulling the email from this file instead of the CMS?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After configuring emails in CMS, you required one more step in order to use those newly created emails.
Go to `System > Configuration > Sales > Sales Emails`
And select your new email templates. Default email templates will be selected by default already. You have to change it from the given select list(your newly created email will be at the end of list)

Comment: Thank you, I see some of the new templates that were created, but the mails are still pulled from the files instead of what we have in the CMS it seems, any idea why this might be?

Comment: So you have selected new templates for sales emails? And cleared Cache?

Comment: Ah yes, as always, the cache was the culprit. Thank you!